# Are curvature forms in complex line bundles symplectic

Tags: differential-forms, vector-bundles, curvature, symplectic-geometry, connections

I know that the curvature form $F_\nabla$ of a connection $\nabla$ in a complex line bundle $L \to B$ is presymplectic (i.e. antisymmetric and closed). Does it also have to be non-degenerate, i.e symplectic (I am excluding the obvious case $F_\nabla = 0$)?

Comment: Are you making any assumptions on $B$ (e.g., even-dimensional, for starters)? Even if $B$ is a compact, complex manifold — even a smooth projective variety — there are lots of examples of line bundles for which this is false.

Comment: @TedShifrin: It's ok if this is false, this is what I was suspecting too, but without being able to quickly find an example to convince myself. I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in [your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1741098/98602) you can make the curvature form anything you want, provided it's closed and lives in the right cohomology class. Most 2-forms are not nondegenerate. In particular, there are manifolds that support no symplectic form (take $S^4$, say...) or cohomology classes $c_1$ such that $c_1^n$ is zero in cohomology, hence cannot be symplectic on a closed manifold.

Comment: This is what I was expecting, I only wanted to make sure.